# No communication between electron app and user AddData on production

Tags: javascript, electron

I created an electron app that has user configuration/settings (changing of theme, tracking and persisting window's current size and position). I saved the json files that contained all of these in user AppData (app.getPath('userData')) working well on development but after being packaged with electron-builder, the app no longer communicates the AppData. Tried to change the theme but the new colors could not be written in AppData, size and position not changing. Frustrated ...

Please what next should I do if I must use the AppData

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
let isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { setColors } = require('./ipc');

const userDir = app.getPath('userData');

let isConfigDir = fs.existsSync(path.join(userDir, 'config'));
let isSizeDir = fs.existsSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/size.json'))
let isPosDir = fs.existsSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/pos.json'));
let isColorDir = fs.existsSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/colors.json'));

//create config dir if not already exists
if(!isConfigDir){
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join(userDir, '/config'))
}

//check and create config files if not already exist
let pos;
if(!isPosDir){
    let pos_ = {"x":636,"y":0};
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/pos.json'), JSON.stringify(pos_));
    pos = pos_
}else{
    pos = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/pos.json'), "utf8"))
}

let size
if(!isSizeDir){
    let size_ = {"width":701,"height":768}
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/size.json'), JSON.stringify(size_));
    size = size_;
}else{
    size = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/size.json'), "utf8"))
}

ipcMain.handle("getColors", (event, args)=>{
    let colors;
    if(!isColorDir){
        let colors_ = {"bg":"gold","text":"#000"}
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/colors.json'), JSON.stringify(colors_));
        colors = colors_
        return colors;
    }else{
        colors = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/colors.json'), "utf8"));
        return colors;
    }
})


let win;
function createWin(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width:size.width,
        height: size.height,
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y,
        title: 'BMS',
        webPreferences:{
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        }
    });
    isDev ? win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000') : win.loadFile('views/build/index.html')

    win.on("closed", ()=>win = null);
    
    // set window size in file size.json when the system resized
    win.on('resized', ()=>{
        let size = {
            width: win.getBounds().width,
            height: win.getBounds().height,
        }
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/size.json'), JSON.stringify(size))
    })

    // set window position in file size.json when the window moves
    win.on('move', ()=>{
        let pos = {
            x: win.getBounds().x,
            y: win.getBounds().y
        }
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(userDir, 'config/pos.json'), JSON.stringify(pos))
    })
}

app.on("ready", ()=>{
    //create window
    createWin();
    
    setColors(userDir)

})


app.on("window-all-closed", ()=>{
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit()
    }
})
app.on('active', ()=>{
    if(win===null){
        createWin()
    }
})
```

Comment: Please share your code as text (using markdown backticks https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) instead of screenshots.

Comment: Okay. Will do that shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now.

So basically.
app.getPath('userData') gives you path up into electron app dir so I have been writing into my electron app directory.

But using app.getPath('appData') get path unto electron app directory level and does not include it. hence won't be packages by electron-builder and it always be in the pc app dir.

```
const appDir = app.getPath('appData');
```

instead of

```
const appDir = app.getPath('userData');
```

I got this from Jay. chatted with him earlier. His youtube channel - ithinktechnologies

Thanks @Guillaume and @Dony for your time. Means a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I suspect that your `/config` folder does not exists when running your application. So, all your variables `isSizeDir`, `isPosDir`, etc. are `false` and stays false even after creating the folder on line 17.

I would move the `/config` folder creation after line 11.

Comment: What I wanted is, if I can writeFiles and readFiles dynamically into user AppData when the app is packaged just the way it works on dev mode. That same codes works as espected on dev but after been packaged with electron-builder, I can no longer writeFiles and readFiles to and fro user AppData. The app is just static.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [electron-json-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-json-storage) package. The package will handle where to put the persisent data depending on the user OS system, and the JSON parsing. You just need to call the package with whatever JS Object you want to store.

I am using this package in my differents electron projects, and it really makes it easy. I recommand using it instead of struggling with the 'fs' Node API.

Comment: Thanks @Dony. Was saving my data in a wrong directory but got it now. The how is below. I really appreciate everyone